# How to store creds securly in React for Playwright tests?

Tags: reactjs, credentials, playwright

I have a react web app which I want to test using Playwright. The app is login-based, meaning I have to login in order to test.
How can I store username and password securely?

They has to exist somewhere in git because I want the tests to be part of the CI and run automatically. That's why I think .env won't help here.

Any ideas? approaches?

Comment: Is it ok for you to have the credentials in plain text in your repo?

Comment: @AlapanDas I would want to avoid that, if possible

Answer (score 1):

Ask your Devops team, how did they handle credentials in CI?

Just give them the credentials and pass these variables in command line when running the tests.

You can use:
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize#passing-environment-variables

Comment: thanks for answering, I will check with them when possible